# C# exception handling in sharepoint know for sure file is not found

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint, http-status-code-404, http-response-codes

This is my Code:

```
   try{
       using (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext context = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(siteURL))
            {
                #region get the name of the file and check if the  file is valid

                context.AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo formsAuthInfo = new
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(UserName, Password);
                context.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = formsAuthInfo;
                File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeFilePath);
                context.Load(file);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                documentName = Convert.ToString(file.Name);                    
                #endregion

    }
    }
    catch(ServerUnauthorizedAccessexception ex)
    {

    }
    catch(WebException We)
    {

    }

    catch (ServerException s)
    {

if (s.Message == "File Not Found.")
{
    htmlClose = "<html><title>Cannot Get File</title><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('The specified file is not found in Sharepoint.');self.close();</script></body></html>";
}
else
{
    htmlClose = "<html><title>Cannot Get File</title><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unable to retrieve file.Please contact your administrator');self.close();</script></body></html>";
}
httpContext.Response.Write(htmlClose);
httpContext.Response.Flush();
    }
```

I want to know if what I have done for 
making sure file not found in sharepoint is correct.

Basically I have used exception message to validate if file is not found in sharepoint.
The code where the exception will get thrown is:

```
    context.Load(file);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have used different catch blocks for catching:ServerUnauthorizedAccessexception,WebException and server exception.
I found that Server exception is the one used to make sure file is not found in sharepoint.
In that part of the code I have done

```
   catch (ServerException s)
   {

   if (s.Message == "File Not Found.")
   {
   htmlClose = "<html><title>Cannot Get File</title><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('The specified file is not found in Sharepoint.');self.close();</script></body></html>";
   }
   else
   {
   htmlClose = "<html><title>Cannot Get File</title><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unable to retrieve file.Please contact your administrator');self.close();</script></body></html>";
   }
   httpContext.Response.Write(htmlClose);
   httpContext.Response.Flush();
   }
```

Comment: What is your current code? I can't quite make sense of the question.

Comment: Don't ever use the `Message` property like that. It is meant to be a human-readable message, and whoever throws the exception has the right to change the message whenever they like.

Answer (score 2):

When you get a `WebException`, you can use the [`Response`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to access the response from the web server (if there is one). You can then cast that to the appropriate subclass, and check the error code:

```
catch (WebException e)
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) e.Response;
    if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        // You got a 404...
    }
}
```

Comment: And for the missing file, he must treat the sharePoint server exception and use its content (maybe type, code, message...)

Comment: @NicolasR: The SharePoint part is unclear to me, to be honest... I'm hoping that this answer gives enough information to help the OP.

Comment: Can I do this:            catch (ServerException s)
            {

                if (s.Message == "File Not Found.")
                {
                    htmlClose = "cannot get file";
                }
                else
                {
                    htmlClose = "<html><title>Cannot Get File</title><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unable to retrieve file.Please contact your administrator');self.close();</script></body></html>";
                }
                httpContext.Response.Write(htmlClose);
                httpContext.Response.Flush();
            }

Comment: @JonSkeet: yes it was a good start that's why I just added a comment.

Comment: @siva: try it (and add breakpoints to see if it is well entering if the exception catch, and the see what is the content of "s" your serverexception)

Comment: Yes it is entering but I am not sure if else will tell that file is found.I am looking for list of possible causes.I think I will leave it here.

Comment: I did it is entering.Will else tell that file is found.I think it can return other exceptions such as httpresponse 404.But I think will be Serverexception if file is not found.

Comment: @siva: I don't know about `ServerException`, but I really wouldn't use the message from the exception as a condition. To be honest, it's very unclear what you're doing and when you're getting which exception.

Comment: context.AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo formsAuthInfo = new
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(UserName, Password);
                    context.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = formsAuthInfo;
                    File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeFilePath);
                    context.Load(file);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: @siva: This should be extra information in the *question* - and I'd strongly advise you to use `using` directives to make your code *much* simpler. Additionally, just showing the code doesn't really tell us much about what's happening. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and make your question clearer.

Comment: I am getting the error when I say context.load(file)

Comment: @siva: As I said before, this should be information *in the question*. Please stop responding in comments. *Fix your question.*

Comment: @siva: No, you really haven't. It's still unclear what the difference is between the two situations, for one thing. Reread your question as if you had come to it for the first time - is it as clear as you'd want it to be? Does it read nicely? (It's currently very fragmented...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have changed question accordingly,Is it correct now?

Comment: @siva: Well it's *better*, although the code is horribly formatted. It makes my answer completely pointless, as you never mention `WebException` now... and I'm afraid I can't answer the part about SharePoint, as I don't use it. I would hope there's a better way of finding out about the exception than just checking the message, but I don't know.